# A region in $\mathbb C$ minus countably many points is path-connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, path-connected

**Edit**: Someone marked my question as a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650693/plane-less-a-finite-number-of-points-is-connected?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, I am asking about proving this result for any open and connected set in the plane and when removing countably many points and not necessarily finite. I know how to prove it when removing finitely many points. Please reopen the question.

I want to prove that if $\Omega$ is a region in the complex plane and if $A$ is a countable subset then $\Omega - A$ is connected. Given $z_1$ and $z_2$ in $\Omega$ we must prove that there is some path in $\Omega$ joining $z_1$ to $z_2$.

Now in case $\Omega$ is the whole complex plane then this can be done by taking a line passing through $z_1$ which does not intersect $A$ and another passing by $z_2$ but neither parallel to the first line nor intersecting A. These two exist since at each point there are uncountable many such lines since if all lines, for instance passing by $z_1$, intersect $A$ then this would contradict the countability of $A$. Let $z_3$ be the intersection of the two lines and thus join $z_1$ to $z_2$ by joining $z_1$ to $z_3$ and then $z_3$ to $z_2$.

I am not sure how to prove the more general case. If we join $z_1$ to $z_2$ by a path $\gamma$ in $\Omega$, then we need to modify this path so that it does not pass by A. Any suggestions how?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip can you please elaborate? The way I proved it for finitely many points is by proving it for one point $a$ and then deduce by induction. To prove it for one point we join $z_1$ and $z_2$ by a path in $\Omega$ and assume it passes by $a$(if not then we are done). We take an open ball around $a$ contained in $\Omega$ and not containing or passing by $z_1$ and $z_2$. We replace the part of the path contained in this ball by the arc joining the first and last points of intersection between the path and the boundary of this ball and hence we get a path joining $z_1$ to $z_2$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip the thing is that when you remove finitely many points from $\Omega$ you will still have an open set and thus you can give such an open ball not passing or containing any points of that finite set. So how can I generalize it for countably many points when I can't guarantee that $\Omega$ remains open upon removing countably many points from it?

Comment: This is exactly the argument of the accepted answer to the duplicate.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip This is exactly how I proved it in case $\Omega$ is the whole complex plane since I can speak of two lines and their intersection there. But in my question $\Omega$ need not be the whole complex plane and that's where my problem specifically lies.

Comment: Ah I see. I missed "Region in $\mathbb C$."

Comment: I deleted my comments and voted to reopen.

Comment: Isn’t it true that you cannot turn an open set into a not-open set by removing countably-many points?  If you could, then there must be some point in the set with only countably-many points in its neighborhood, which seems impossible.

Comment: @user3716267 This is false even in $\Bbb R$: If you remove all points $1/n$, $n\in\Bbb N$, $0$ is left in the set but has no neighborhood contained in the set, so the set is not open.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you can “pierce” the neighborhood cleverly.  It seems like you can only do this locally in a countable number of places though, so we should still be able to patch around it…

Comment: @user3716267 remove all rationals, no point admits an open neigbourhood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a similar argument as in the case of $\Bbb C$. The important trick is to reduce to the following case:

> **Lemma.** Let $X$ be a countable subset of the unit ball $B_1(0)$. Then $B_1(0)-X$ is path connected.

Proof:

Let $x,y\in B_1(0)-X$. For $z\in B_1(0)-X$ let $[x,z]$ and $[y,z]$ denote the paths $\{t x+(1-t)z\mid t\in[0,1]\}$ and $\{ty+(1-t)z\mid t\in[0,1]\}$. These paths are contained entirely $B_1(0)$ and if $z_1\neq z_2$ with $x-z_1$ and $x-z_2$ not proportional to each other then $[x,z_1]\cap [x,z_2] = \{x\}$.

So, since $X$ is countable, there are uncountably many $z$ for which both $[x,z]\cap X$ or $[y,z]\cap X$ are empty. Pick one $z$ for which it is empty and then $[x,z]\cup [y,z]$ gives a path from $x$ to $y$ in $B_1(0)-X$.

The above obviously also implies:

> For any $\epsilon >0$ and $x\in \Bbb C$ and countable $X$ the ball $B_\epsilon(x)-X$ is path connected.

Now to show the statement you are interested in. $\Omega$ is open and connected, so it is path connected. Let $x,y\in \Omega-X$ and let $\gamma:[0,1]\to \Omega$ be a path connecting $x$ and $y$. Since the image of this path is compact and $\Omega$ is open there are $x_1,...,x_n$ and $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n$ so that
$$\gamma([0,1])\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^n B_{\epsilon_k}(x_k)\subseteq \Omega$$
Now each of the $B_{\epsilon_k}(x_k)-X$ are path connected and the intersection of two neighbouring balls is non-empty. Hence their union is path connected and there is a path connecting $x\in \bigcup_{k=1}^n B_{\epsilon_k}(x_k) -X$ to $y$ which lies in the same set.

Comment: For the implication that $B_\epsilon \setminus X$ is our interval not just $[0,\epsilon]$?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, sorry.